# How do I stop my system from shutting down or freezing randomly?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I've got something of a problem here. Lately (the past month) my computer's been **randomly locking up** even with the simplest of tasks, **or shutting down with no warning at all** (In fact, it locked up typing this, so I had to borrow a laptop to continue...). There was even one time where it failed to even discover the operating system upon booting until I'd manually selected it from the options!

I've run diagnostics, consulted a shop (All of which found no issue with anything), and even sent it back to the company, whom also could find nothing to be the problem. Overall **temperatures appear normal**, everything's **secure and clean**, and even antivirus checks done remotely have shown nothing. I would try a system repair, but unfortunately the preinstall did not come with a CD...despite my insistence and willingness to pay extra at the time.

The model I'm working with has **Windows 7 Home Premium**, relatively new from Hewlett-Packard...any and all help will be appreciated, and I'll do what I can to obtain more information.

**What I do know right now**, however:

- When it first started, we assumed it was the CPU or the power supply.
  Replaced both, made sure there were no compatibility issues...but the
  problems flared up worse than before within 12 hours of the parts
  being installed.
- The RAM is in perfect working order, a trio of Kingston 2gb ram
  sticks.
- The system seems quite willing to run idle for around two or three
  hours, but will immediately lock up afterwards if you perform any
  task.
- Heavy gaming or even light browsing seem to have no impact at all as
  to when these issues occur.
- Careful examination has revealed no damage to the board, and so far
  everything seems to be connected-all the fans run, the heat sink is
  certainly doing its job, and then some.

I'll try and answer any questions I can; thank you for your time!

Comment: How did you verify the memory is working exactly?

Comment: I'm curious as to the answer to that question myself.  Also, can you expand a bit as to what happened when you said it didn't discover the OS?  Did it not find the hard drive?  Or did it find the drive, just not the OS on it?  I suspect the issue may be with the motherboard itself (Specifically, the drive controller) or the hard drive.  Is it a laptop?  If it is, then I'd probably lean more towards the hard drive failing, most likely due to being dropped/placed down too heavily.

Comment: Booting a live cd would unearth MOUNDS of info. See if you can replicate the problem with a live Ubuntu cd. If you can boot fine and do basic tasks in a live environment I would lean towards OS problems or possibly HDD issues.